# IIS7 + WCF + Silverlight problems

Tags: wcf, silverlight, iis-7

I've been building a silverlight application and a WCF service for a while now and recently tried to host them in IIS7.

I installed IIS7 on Windows Server 2008 R2 and added these two application to my default website. I am having a number of problems so im hoping one of you can help out...

1) The silverlight and WCF service applications do not work with pass-through authentication. I need to "connect as" the administrator server account when setting up the application. I read online that you should only need to use the "connect as" field when you are connecting to another computer. If i dont supply the admin credentials i get this error. Do i have to set up permissions somewhere else?

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error The requested page cannot be
>   accessed because the related configuration data for the page is
>   invalid. Detailed Error Information Module IIS Web Core Notification
>   BeginRequest Handler Not yet determined Error Code 0x80070005 Config
>   Error Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions
>   Config File \?\C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\My Dropbox\Research
>   Masters\Project\WCFService\Website\web.config Requested URL
>   http:://localhost:80/WCFService/Service.svc Physical Path
>   C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\My Dropbox\Research
>   Masters\Project\WCFService\Website\Service.svc Logon Method Not yet
>   determined Logon User Not yet determined Config Source    -1: 
>       0:  Links and More Information This error occurs when there is a
>   problem reading the configuration file for the Web server or Web
>   application. In some cases, the event logs may contain more
>   information about what caused this error.

2) Visual studio generated 2 webpages to run my silverlight application (.html and .aspx). When I am running the silverlight application (connected as admin) I can navigate to the .html page, no problem. When I try to open the .aspx file i get the following error

> Server Error in '/Platform' Application.
>
> Access is denied.
>
> Description: An error occurred while accessing the resources required
>   to serve this request. You might not have permission to view the
>   requested resources.
>
> Error message 401.3: You do not have permission to view this directory
>   or page using the credentials you supplied (access denied due to
>   Access Control Lists). Ask the Web server's administrator to give you
>   access to 'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\My Dropbox\Research
>   Masters\Project\Platform\Website\PlatformTestPage.aspx'.
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30128;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30128.1

3) The WCF service runs fine (again, connected as admin) until i restart the server. When i try to run the WCF service after a reboot, the mysql assembly seems to be missing from the solution. If i just rebuilt the solution and run the service again... it works (until next restart). Whats causing this error?

Solution here - http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=5yasqx&s=5

> Server Error in '/WCFService' Application.
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.2.2.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its
>   dependencies. Access is denied.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.2.2.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. Access is
>   denied.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.2.2.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' could not be loaded.
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data,
>   Version=6.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or
>   one of its dependencies. Access is denied.]
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean
>   forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark,
>   Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +567
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) +192    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString) +35
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String
>   constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses) +243
>   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.CreateService(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath) +1423
>   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath) +50
>   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath) +1132
>
> [ServiceActivationException: The service '/WCFService/Service.svc'
>   cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The
>   exception message is: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data,
>   Version=6.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or
>   one of its dependencies. Access is denied..]
>   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +889824
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult
>   result) +179150
>   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.OnAsyncEventCompletion(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +107
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30128;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30128.1

Thats about it, hope someone reads this message, I wasted most of the weekend trying to fix these problems on my own... thanks

Comment: This is my first time using IIS7 so this is all new to me at the moment so I have no idea how to set up the server correctly, I'm just learning as I go. The first two seem to be access denied alright. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestions:

1) Check your web application folder's permissions. You should edit the permissions on your web application folder so that the IIS user can read from the folder. 
So you should open the folder properties dialog for the folder in the windows explorer and check if the application pool user has at least read permissions. If you didn't provide another user for the application pool, then the default user should be IIS_IUSRS.

2) Check if the asp.net is enabled in your system by running:

If you have .Net 4 installed in your system:
"%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe" –i
Otherwise:
"%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe" –i

The above command will register/repair the your .Net installation with the IIS.

3) Is your mysql dll locate in the bin folder? I would check if you also have permissions to read this folder. If the dll is not in the same folder as your application dll, check if the dll is installed in the GAC.

Regards,

Comment: So when you say "edit the permissions" on the folder do you mean doing it through windows explorer, properties, security tab and adding the ISS user (closest thing I could find was ISS_IUSRS - that right?). If you have to do something in IIS Manager could you be more specific. I've just started to use IIS and have no idea what i'm doing. In relation to your mysql answer. The mysql.dll file is located in the WCF service library directory, referenced in the project and is copied to the bin folder once compiled. When I compile the WCF service website it imports the mysql.dll and library.dll files

Comment: I mean edit permissions with the windows explorer and check if the user of your application pool has read permission. If you didn't change the user, the default should be IIS_IUSRS.

Answer (score 0):

1)Give permissions to the folder for the IIS_IUSRS group.
Also see if the application pool for the application in IIS manager->"Application Pools" has the Identity set as "LocalSystem". For me it was "NetworkService", setting it to "LocalSystem" solved it.

Answer (score -3):

You must not be able to host silverlight applications with IIS7.
Try hosting your silverlight app on an apache server with a php / html script.

Hope that helps mate
Please rate my answer

Anzwerx